# Optimizing SQL query with multiple filtering conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm wrapping my head around a query that just almost ruined our release with its 2m execution time and extensive CPU consumption. To apply the right preventive action for the team in the future, I first need to understand if the query design is fundamentally wrong (problem in development) or one can discover the problem only on a larger production-like testing database.

Query SQL (generated by Sequelize):

```sql
-- 26 000 000 + records in join
SELECT [Answer].[uuid],
       [Answer].[id],
       [Answer].[questionId],
       [Answer].[data],
       [Answer].[deletedAt],
       [Answer].[reportId],
       [Answer].[sysStartTime]
FROM [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].[Answers] AS [Answer]
         INNER JOIN [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].[VisitReports] AS [VisitReport]
                    ON [Answer].[reportId] = [VisitReport].[id]
WHERE (           -- 8
                  [Answer].[uuid] IN (N'ea318a76-c50b-4f11-86c7-2eff1e0da210', N'2ad2191a-f125-44eb-bd76-11ba51d9b999',
                                      N'54491b3c-3c17-41bd-a993-25a5288e5465', N'38e99642-4138-460d-b1ac-0db7a99c51d6',
                                      N'0014b34d-6f2d-4cfd-a678-457e6d991291', N'2796e583-a2ed-41b1-b5a8-3e3133a08905',
                                      N'452cf55f-f13c-4aca-a012-56fc800758a5', N'18397ce1-8405-48da-858b-b825c95bffa2')
              OR
                  --784 718 records meeting the time criteria
                  ([Answer].[sysStartTime] > '2022-05-01') and (
                          -- * 25 comparisons = 19 600 000
                          [VisitReport].[siteId] IN
                          (166011, 167672, 169027, 169723, 169728,
                           170529, 170530, 170541, 173914, 173917,
                           174659, 174660, 174666, 175748, 176748,
                           176767, 181641, 181679, 181688, 181700,
                           181704, 181965, 182056, 183365, 184252
                              ))
          )
ORDER BY [Answer].[reportId] ASC, [Answer].[id] ASC
```

Indexes are set for all the columns used in WHERE clause, but they are not being utilized (full index scan)

DDL:

```sql
-- VisitReports table

create table VisitReports
(
  id int identity
    primary key,
  authorIsid nvarchar(255) not null,
  localId nvarchar(255)
    constraint UC_VisitReports_localId
      unique,
  status varchar(255)
    check ([status]='completed' OR [status]='filed' OR [status]='sent' OR [status]='finalized' OR [status]='reviewed' OR [status]='submitted' OR [status]='draft'),
  submitted datetime2,
  reviewed datetime2,
  finalized datetime2,
  sent datetime2,
  filed datetime2,
  visitType nvarchar(255) not null,
  visitMode nvarchar(255) not null,
  questionnaireVersion int not null,
  visitDates nvarchar(max),
  startDate date,
  endDate date,
  locations nvarchar(255),
  sponsorParticipants nvarchar(max),
  siteParticipants nvarchar(max),
  link nvarchar(255),
  excludedCategories nvarchar(255),
  createdAt datetime2 not null,
  updatedAt datetime2 not null,
  deletedAt datetime2,
  reviewerId int
    references Contacts
      on delete set null,
  siteId int not null
    references Sites
      on delete cascade,
  visitId nvarchar(255)
    constraint UC_VisitReports_visitId
      unique,
  reviewedWithComments bit,
  uploadError nvarchar(max),
  modifiedByIsid nvarchar(255),
  auditEvent nvarchar(255),
  auditReason nvarchar(255),
  sysStartTime datetime2 constraint DF_VisitReports_sysStart default sysutcdatetime() not null,
  sysEndTime datetime2 constraint DF_VisitReports_sysEnd default CONVERT([datetime2],'9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999') not null,
  filehash nvarchar(255),
  remoteVisitDates nvarchar(max) default '[]' not null,
  onSiteVisitDates nvarchar(max) default '[]' not null
)
go

create index IX_VisitReports_authorIsid
  on VisitReports (authorIsid)
go

create index IX_VisitReports_authorIsid_deletedAt
  on VisitReports (authorIsid) include (deletedAt)
go

create index IX_VisitReports_siteId
  on VisitReports (siteId)
go



--Answers table

create table Answers
(
  id int identity
    primary key,
  localId nvarchar(255),
  questionId nvarchar(255) not null,
  data nvarchar(max),
  createdAt datetime2 not null,
  updatedAt datetime2 not null,
  deletedAt datetime2,
  reportId int not null
    references VisitReports
      on delete cascade,
  modifiedByIsid nvarchar(255),
  auditEvent nvarchar(255),
  auditReason nvarchar(255),
  sysStartTime datetime2 constraint DF_Answers_sysStart default sysutcdatetime() not null,
  sysEndTime datetime2 constraint DF_Answers_sysEnd default CONVERT([datetime2],'9999-12-31 23:59:59.9999999') not null,
  lastModifiedTs datetime2 constraint DF_answers_lastModifiedTs default '2016-01-01',
  uuid uniqueidentifier constraint DF_Answers_uuid default newid() not null
    constraint UC_Answers_uuid
      unique
)
go

create unique index UIX_Answers_reportId_questionId_deletedAt
  on Answers (reportId, questionId, deletedAt) include (id, localId, data, createdAt)
go

create index IX_Answers_reportId_questionId
  on Answers (reportId, questionId)
go

create index IX_Answers_reportId
  on Answers (reportId)
go

create index IX_Answers_sysStartTime
  on Answers (sysStartTime)
go
```

Execution plan
[image]

[image]

My thoughts are going this way so far:

- Query selects some 26 milion records in the JOIN and running it through a set of filtering conditions that cannot be much simplified, for example by taking some part of it right into the JOIN to reduce the amount of comparisons later on
- Problem may not be in the DB engine or its ability to find the 'right' execution plan, but rather the query design and number of necessary value comparisons.

  The condition for [Answer].[sysStartTime] > '2022-05-01' reaches 784 000 records
  For each of this records we are checking if siteId is on the list (19 600 000 comparisons)
  Then the first part of the OR adds some complexity as well, possibly multiply the comparisons by another 8, which would get it to some 156 800 000 operations?
- parameters coming to the query are different each time, so the explain plan needs to be re-generated and engine cannot cache the results.

We fixed the query by splitting it in two separate ones. But my question here would be:

Would you say these `WHERE` conditions are a bad design right away or it is something that an engine with enough resources (in our case 12 CPU, 80GB RAM) should handle and problem is elsewhere? Does detection of this kind of problems require a testing database of production proportions or it can be easily detected on lower environments with small data?

Comment: For performance issues we really need the full table schema, indexes and actual execution plan (paste the plan). Use of `or` like this is never a good performer, often two separate unioned queries will work better because the optimiser can better utilise indexes.

Comment: Thank you! I've posted the DDL and a different view of the execution plan, hopefully it will help. Unfortunately I don't know how to get it raw and readable at the same time from IntelliJ.

Comment: I've no idea what application is generating that nonstandard graphical plan, but a graphical plan is mostly useless, provide [the actual execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan) from SSMS or using showplan xml. We don't need things like triggers - although I note you should probably be using *temporal tables* instead of triggers.

Comment: Your RDBMS machine provisioning is almost certainly sufficient unless you have many active concurrent connections.

Comment: The selectivity of your index on sysStartTime is questionable, so it is unlikely that the optimizer will choose index intersection. And since there's no index that includes both `uuid` and `sysStartTime`, what's left for the optimizer is a table scan ("clustered index scan").

Comment: If you use SSMS -- Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio -- this tip is for you: Right-click in a query window, then select Show Actual Execution Plan, then run the query. The execution plan display sometimes recommends a new index to create.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the answers, I'll try the SQL Studio for more insights. But since I'm on mac the fist choice was IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stu was correct on doing a union first, so each part of that can pre-qualify each individual part of the query by its better index and come up with a unique list of IDs.  From that, THEN get the actual details.  For the indexes, I would have the following to assist

```
Table         Index
Answers       ( uuid, id )
Answers       ( sysStartTime, reportId )
VisitReports  ( id, siteid )

select
        a.uuid,
        a.id,
        a.questionId,
        a.data,
        a.deletedAt,
        a.reportId,
        a.sysStartTime
    from
        ( select 
                a.id
            from
                [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].Answers a
            where
                a.uuid in ( N'ea318a76-c50b-4f11-86c7-2eff1e0da210', 
                            N'2ad2191a-f125-44eb-bd76-11ba51d9b999',
                            N'54491b3c-3c17-41bd-a993-25a5288e5465', 
                            N'38e99642-4138-460d-b1ac-0db7a99c51d6',
                            N'0014b34d-6f2d-4cfd-a678-457e6d991291', 
                            N'2796e583-a2ed-41b1-b5a8-3e3133a08905',
                            N'452cf55f-f13c-4aca-a012-56fc800758a5', 
                            N'18397ce1-8405-48da-858b-b825c95bffa2' )
            UNION
            select
                    a.id
                from
                    [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].Answers a
                         JOIN [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].VisitReports vr
                            ON a.reportId = vr.id
                        -- * 25 comparisons = 19 600 000
                        and vr.siteId IN
                                ( 166011, 167672, 169027, 169723, 169728,
                                  170529, 170530, 170541, 173914, 173917,
                                  174659, 174660, 174666, 175748, 176748,
                                  176767, 181641, 181679, 181688, 181700,
                                  181704, 181965, 182056, 183365, 184252 )
                where
                    a.sysStartTime > '2022-05-01' ) pq
            JOIN [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].Answers a
                on pq.id = a.id
    ORDER BY 
        a.reportId, 
        a.id
```

One adjustment MIGHT be to swap the index for the UNIONED part of the inner prequery. Not knowing your data, filtering on the site ID first, then joining to answers might be better. However, looking at only answers with a start time of May 1 this year might be smaller than per site every year. If so, I would have an index on the visit report table on ( siteid, id ) vs original sample and change the union portion to

```
        UNION
        select
                a.id
            from
                [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].VisitReports vr
                    JOIN [NORTHAMERICA\ourappname].Answers a
                        ON vr.id = a.reportId
                        AND a.sysStartTime > '2022-05-01' 
            where
                -- * 25 comparisons = 19 600 000
                vr.siteId IN
                    ( 166011, 167672, 169027, 169723, 169728,
                        170529, 170530, 170541, 173914, 173917,
                        174659, 174660, 174666, 175748, 176748,
                        176767, 181641, 181679, 181688, 181700,
                        181704, 181965, 182056, 183365, 184252 ) ) pq
```

Comment: Thank you, we chose to split the query in a similar way and it is pretty fast. My take is that one has to be very careful when nesting multiple conditions including the IN operator that can contain long list of items. I believe more realistic tasting data combined with application performance monitoring with a DB insight could highlight the problem earlier. 
We have implemented Elastic APM which is great for measuring the execution time and uncovering the underperforming queries.